# How can we add automatic captions to video in flutter app development

Tags: caption, video-subtitles

Is there any library or dependency in Flutter to add automatic captions to video flutter app.? Like YouTube without uploading SRT file. It should sync automatically. Please help.

I have tried which are need to be uploaded SRT files but I need to do it by automatic captions syncing.